# Python divide multiple columns by values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've done some google, but couldn't find what I want. Most of the questions are updating values of a column from another columns. My situation is that I need to update the columns of a data frame with values from another data frame.

```
>>> print(df1)
  country road  score1  score2  score3
0      us   m1      10      20      30
1      us   m2      20      30      40
2  canada   m3      30      40      50
3  canada   m4      40      50      60
4  canada   m5      50      60      70

>>> print(df2)
  country road  divider
0      us   m1       10
1      us   m2       20
2  canada   m3       30
3  canada   m4       40
4  canada   m5       50
```

The expected result:

```
  country road  score1    score2    score3
0      us   m1     1.0  2.000000  3.000000
1      us   m2     1.0  1.500000  2.000000
2  canada   m3     1.0  1.333333  1.666667
3  canada   m4     1.0  1.250000  1.500000
4  canada   m5     1.0  1.200000  1.400000
```

Each value in the result data frame is obtained by dividing the values in `df1` by the corresponding values in `df2`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` in both `DataFrame`s by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), so possible divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df = (df1.set_index(['country','road'])
         .div(df2.set_index(['country','road'])['divider'], axis=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  country road  score1    score2    score3
0      us   m1     1.0  2.000000  3.000000
1      us   m2     1.0  1.500000  2.000000
2  canada   m3     1.0  1.333333  1.666667
3  canada   m4     1.0  1.250000  1.500000
4  canada   m5     1.0  1.200000  1.400000
```